# Error The component for the router must be an react component

Tags: react-native

Environment

React native: 0.61

react-native navigation:4.0

Deployed os : Android 9 pie

```
import {createAppContainer} from 'react-navigation';
import {createStackNavigator} from 'react-navigation-stack';
import Signup from './Signup';
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Home from './Home';
import EditProfile from './Editprofile';
import Payments from './Payments';
import Refer from './Refer';
import { createDrawerNavigator } from 'react-navigation-drawer';

export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {

    return <Appcont />;
  }
}
const appi = createStackNavigator(
  {
    signup: {
      screen: ()=><Signup/>
    },
     home: {
        screen: ()=><Home/>
      },
      editProfile:{
        screen:()=><EditProfile/>
      },
      payments:{
        screen:()=><Payments/>
      },
      refer:{
        screen:()=><Refer/>
      }
    },
    {
      initialRouteName:'signup'
    }

);


const MyDrawerNavigator = createDrawerNavigator(appi,{
  initialRouteName: 'signup',
    headerMode:'float',
  contentOptions: {
    activeTintColor: '#e91e63',
  }
});

const Appcont = createAppContainer(MyDrawerNavigator);
```

home.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Text, View,Image } from 'react-native';


 class Home extends Component {
  static navigationOptions = {
    title:'Home',
  drawerLabel: 'Home',
  drawerIcon: ({ tintColor }) => (
    <Image
      source={require('./img/Homepng.png')}
      style={{width:20,height:20}}
    />
  ),headerShown:'true'
};
  render() {

    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: "center", alignItems: "center" }}>
        <Text>Hello, home</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
export default Home;
```

When I run the above code it throws me an error !!!
Error The component for the router must be a react component

I have seen all the issues related to this and rectified as much I can but I am still getting this error I don't know why?

Answer (score 1):

you can try to change the

```
const appi = createStackNavigator(
  {
    signup: {
      screen: ()=><Signup/>
    },
}
```

to

```
const appi = createStackNavigator({
  signup: {
    screen: Signup,
  },
});
```

At the same time ,the Singup have to extend React.Component, and remember export it. and `() => <Home/>` is not a component. it is function object

```
export defalut class Sigup extends React.component
```

Comment: React.Component and Compenent is same right, then why ?

Comment: yes, it is the same. If your component extends it, I think  `()=><Signup/>` is the wrong occurs place

Comment: you use (`()=><Home/>`) , try to change it to `<Home/>`